# Trigger on account for contact with type new and renew

Tags: apex, trigger

I have to write a trigger for account which has two related contacts one with type new and other with renew if there are 2 contacts with this type then the checkbox isActive on account should be allowed to check else there should be an error
I have written this code but it is not bulkified please anyone can help me

```
public class AccountIfContactIsNewAndRenewHandler {

public static void isCheckAccount(List<Account>accList){
    for(Account a:accList){
        if(a.IsActive__c==true){
            a.addError('Cannot update isActive field now first create contacts');
        }
    }
}

public static void isCheckContact(List<Account>accList){
    System.debug('Trigger.new'+accList);
    Integer newStatus=0;
    Integer renewStatus=0;
    Set<Id> accId=new Set<Id>();

    for(Account a:accList){
        accId.add(a.Id);
    }
    System.debug('accList'+accList);
    System.debug('accId'+accId);
   // List<Contact> con=new List<Contact>[Select Id,Name Type__c From Contact Wh];
    map<Id,List<Contact>> accountContactMap = new map<id,List<Contact>>();

   List<Account> lstAccount = [SELECT Id,
                                      name,
                                      IsActive__c,
                                (SELECT Id,
                                        Name,
                                        Type__c
                                 FROM   Contacts
                                 Where Type__c=:'New'
                                 Or Type__c=:'Renew') 
                                FROM   Account 
                                Where Id IN :accId];

    for(Account acc : lstAccount)
    {
        accountContactMap.put(acc.id, acc.Contacts);
    }
    System.debug(accountContactMap);

    for (List<Contact> outerList : accountContactMap.values())
    {
        for(Contact con:outerList){
            System.debug('Type'+con.Type__c);
            if(con.Type__c=='New'){
                newStatus=newStatus+1;
                System.debug('newStatus'+newStatus);
            }
            else if(con.Type__c=='Renew'){
                renewStatus=renewStatus+1;
                System.debug('renewStatus'+renewStatus);

            }
        }
    } 

        for(Account a : accList){
            if(a.IsActive__c==true){
                if(newStatus>0 && renewStatus>0)
                {
                    System.debug('You can update');

                    a.IsActive__c=true;
                }
                else 
                {
                    a.addError('You should have atleast 1 contact of type new and 1 of type renew');
                    a.IsActive__c=false;
                }
            }
        } 
    }       
}
```

Also i have to avoid for within for please tell me the solution

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. When you say this code "isn't bulkified", what do you mean? To me, this does look bulkified. I don't see any queries or DML inside of loops. Also, it'd help if you explained (by making an [edit] to your question) _why_ you're trying to avoid nested loops. Nested loops aren't inherently evil, and are almost a requirement if you're iterating over a nested collection of data (such as the accounts with a list of related contacts that you appear to be working with).

Comment: If i try to update  many records which don't have contacts of type new and renew then also the record gets updated why is that so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to offer an improved version of the original answer by @Maria Illarionova by removing the nested loops and fixing one potential error

```
public static void processAccounts(Map<Id, Account> accounts) {
    List<Contact> contactsToCheck = [
            SELECT Id, Type__c, AccountId
            FROM Contact 
            WHERE (Type__c = 'New' OR Type__c = 'Renew') AND Accountid IN :accounts.keySet()
    ];

    Set<Id> accountsWithNew = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> accountsWithRenew = new Set<Id>();

   for (Contact c : contactsToCheck) {  
      if (c.Type__c == 'New') {
         accountsWithNew.put(c.AccountId);
      } else if (c.Type__c == 'Renew') {
         accountsWithRenew.put(c.AccountId);
      }

   }

    for (Account acc_i : accounts.values()) {
        Boolean hasNewCon = accountsWithNew.contains(acc_i.Id);
        Boolean hasRenewCon = accountsWithRenew.contains(acc_i.Id);

        if (hasNewCon && hasRenewCon) {
            System.debug('You can update');
            acc_i.IsActive__c = true;
        } else {
            acc_i.addError('You should have at least 1 contact of type new and 1 of type renew');
            acc_i.IsActive__c = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me thank you so much for your help

Comment: I’m glad it did! Please feel free to mark the answer as accepted so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass to your trigger handler Trigger.newMap and process account in bulk with the following actions:

1. Select all related contacts one time, before the loop.
2. Run through your account and check all related contacts.

```
public static void processAccounts(Map<Id, Account> accounts) {
    List<Contact> contactsToCheck = new List<Contact>();
    contactsToCheck = [
            SELECT Id, Type__c 
            FROM Contact 
            WHERE (Type__c = 'New' OR Type__c = 'Renew') AND Accountid IN :accounts.keySet()
    ];

    for (Account acc_i : accounts.values()) {
        Integer newCon = 0;
        Integer renewCon = 0;
        for (Contact con_i : contactsToCheck) {
            if (con_i.AccountId == acc_i.Id) {
                if (con_i.Type__c == 'New') {
                    newCon = newCon + 1;
                } else if (con_i.Type__c == 'Renew') {
                    renewCon = renewCon + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        if (newCon > 0 && renewCon > 0) {
            System.debug('You can update');
            acc_i.IsActive__c = true;
        } else {
            acc_i.addError('You should have at least 1 contact of type new and 1 of type renew');
            acc_i.IsActive__c = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it s not working it is showing error if there is contacts of type new and renew . Also i don't want to use nested for loop. so if you can please help me with this

Comment: What error is it showing? You should help the person answering your question by providing clear, concise detail about any errors you find with their code.

Comment: Sorry but it was showing error even if there were contacts of type new and renew

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou for your help but I still have one query how to fire trigger only when there is an update in checkbox field elsewhere trigger should not fire . Could you please help.This is my updated code.
public class AccountIfContactIsNewAndRenewHandler { 
    public static void processAccounts(Map accMap,ListoldList,ListnewList) {
        Map maptoverifyoldaccount =new Map();
        Boolean ifupdate;
        for(Account evtOld : oldList) { 
            maptoverifyoldaccount.put(evtOld.Id, evtOld); 
        }
        for(Account evtNew : newList) {
            if(evtNew.IsActive__c==true){

```
            if(evtNew.IsActive__c != maptoverifyoldaccount.get(evtNew.Id).IsActive__c) {
                System.debug('Checkbox is update');
                ifupdate=true;  
            }
        }
    }
    Boolean status;
    System.debug('accMap'+accMap);
    if(ifupdate==true){
        List<Contact> contactsList = [SELECT Id, 
                                      Type__c,
                                      AccountId
                                      FROM   Contact 
                                      WHERE  (Type__c = 'New' OR Type__c = 'Renew') 
                                      AND    AccountId IN :accMap.keySet()];

        System.debug('contactsList'+contactsList);
        Set<Id> accountsWithNew = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> accountsWithRenew = new Set<Id>();

        for (Contact c : contactsList) {  
            if (c.Type__c == 'New') {
                accountsWithNew.add(c.AccountId);
                System.debug('accountsWithNew'+accountsWithNew);
            } 
            else if (c.Type__c == 'Renew') {
                accountsWithRenew.add(c.AccountId);
                System.debug('accountsWithRenew'+accountsWithRenew);
            }

        }

        for (Account acc_i : accMap.values()) {

            if(accountsWithNew.contains(acc_i.Id) && accountsWithRenew.contains(acc_i.Id)){
                status=true;
            }

            if (status==true) {
                System.debug('You can update');
                //acc_i.IsActive__c = true;

            } 
            else {
                acc_i.IsActive__c.addError('You should have at least 1 contact of type new and 1 of type renew to check this checkbox');
                //acc_i.IsActive__c = false;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

}
Actually its working for single record but not for bulk so plase provide a suggestion